# How to get only unique values from array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i am trying to count all multiple value in array and display in one array.

```
Array
(
[0] => unicomp6.unicomp.net 
[1] => 
[2] => burger.letters.com 
[3] => 
[4] => burger.letters.com 
[5] => 
[6] => burger.letters.com 
[7] => 
[8] => 
[9] => d104.aa.net 
[10] => 
[11] => unicomp6.unicomp.net 
[12] => 
[13] => 
[14] => unicomp6.unicomp.net 
[15] => 
[16] => unicomp6.unicomp.net 
[17] => 
[18] => d104.aa.net 
[19] => 
[20] => d104.aa.net 
[21] => 
)
```

output result would be like that.

```
 Array
 (
 [unicomp6.unicomp.net ] => 4
 [burger.letters.com ] => 3
 [d104.aa.net] => 3
)
```

I have written this code but i want to know how to merge all the unique value in array ,please help me how can iphp  do it:

```
$j=0;
 $arrayName = array();
 foreach ($host_name as $key => $value) {

    $size= sizeof($host_name);

   if($value!='')
   {       
    $count=1;
    for ($k=0; $k<$size; $k++) { 

        if($host_name[$j]==$host_name[$k])
        {

            $arrayName = array($host_name[$j]=> $count++);
        }
    }
 }   
         $j++;
 }
    print_r($arrayName);
```

Comment: `array_count_values`

Comment: Many dups for counting duplicate values in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php

    $data=Array
    (
       'unicomp6.unicomp.net','','burger.letters.com','','burger.letters.com','','burger.letters.com','','','d104.aa.net','unicomp6.unicomp.net','','unicomp6.unicomp.net','d104.aa.net','','d104.aa.net',''
    );
  echo"<pre>";
print_r(array_count_values(array_filter($data)));
echo"</pre>";
```

And the output after trimmed the empty fields :

```
Array
(
    [unicomp6.unicomp.net] => 3
    [burger.letters.com] => 3
    [d104.aa.net] => 3
)
```